# Pin annotation displaying the current location

Tags: ios, mkpinannotationview

I use the MKPinAnnotationView for pin annotation.Can i possibly display the curent address of the location as the pin annotation if i move the pin randomly on the map?

Comment: Have you looked at the MKReverseGeocoder class or the sample app [CurrentAddress](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CurrentAddress/Introduction/Intro.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the MKReverseGeocoder class.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008323